# Proving a fact about continuous function

Tags: calculus, continuity

Prove that if $f(a)>0$ and $f$ is continuous, then there is a $\delta >0$ such that for all $x$, $|x-a|< \delta$ implies $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? If you write down the definition of continuity, this is almost trivial.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\epsilon=\frac{f(a)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\epsilon=\frac{f(a)}{2}$ and apply the definition of continuity (in terms of $\epsilon,\delta$) on $a$.

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac{f(a)}2$, there is a $\delta >0$  such that $ |x-a|< \delta $ then

$$|f(x)-f(a)|<\frac{f(a)}2$$

hence

$$- \frac{f(a)}2\lt f(x)-f(a)<\frac{f(a)}2$$

so $ f(x)\gt \frac{f(a)}2$